# Join 4 tables in DB with Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2005

in my database there is a table has 3 FK to other 3 tables i want to select the data in this table + data in the other 3 tables when the FK value = the PK values in the other tables

Comment: http://sqlzoo.net/ - introduction to basic SQL querying.

Comment: this is very basic indeed. no offence, but if you can't figure this out you probably shouldn't be writing any sql at all, go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @RPM1984: No offence, but if you don't want to answer questions you probably shouldn't be on StackOverflow at all. There's nothing wrong with asking a rudimentary question like this, as evidenced by the fact that the greatest living SQList answered it.

Comment: I do like answering questions. The point i was making is...ah forget it. I withdraw my comment.

Comment: ok no offense but if you work in 3 projects ,, haven't slept in 3 days the dead lines in 3 days in row ,, i think small thing is the hardest things now ,, but any way thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.Field1, t2.Field2, t3.Field3, t4.Field4
FROM Table t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID
    INNER JOIN Table4 t4 ON t1.ID = t4.ID
```

If there aren't always matching rows in Tables 2 - 4, and you want those records return still then change the INNER JOINs to LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t1
JOIN    t2
ON      t2.id = t1.t2_id
JOIN    t3
ON      t3.id = t1.t3_id
JOIN    t4
ON      t4.id = t1.t4_id
```

Comment: Additionally, this will only show items that actually have values for t2_id, t3_id, and t4_id. If you want to show the records in t1, even if the t2_id is null, do a LEFT OUTER JOIN, instead of a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ParentTable as pt
LEFT JOIN table1 as t1
ON pt.t1_ID = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2
ON pt.t2_ID= t2.ID
LEFT JOIN table3 as t3
ON pt.t3_ID= t3.ID
```

This will return a record even if there are not matches in table1,2 or 3.  @Ada and @Q's will exclude those records.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TBL1 T1
RIGHT JOIN TBL2  T2 
ON T1.id = T2.id
RGIHT JOIN TBL3 T3 
ON T3.id = T2.id

This will return all the records from Right table and matching records from Left table.